# Making a TPageControl flat in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I don't know whether this question can be answered here, but I hope it will.
I wrote a simple text editor in Delphi 7 that serves as my primary IDE for writing C code under Windows. I run Windows in a VM and I needed something light.
In any case, it uses a TpageControl that gets a new tab whenever you open or create a new file. Pretty standard. 
Now, the TPageControl under Delphi has no flat property.

**NO I don't mean setting the tab style to tsButtons or tsFlatButtons**

the borders cannot be set to "none" and it looks pretty bad when you add a text editor into the tab control.

Is there any way to make a TpageControl flat?

**EDIT**:

On an open source PageControl that supports flat here's what I found:

```
procedure TCustomTabExtControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if(Message.Msg=TCM_ADJUSTRECT) and (FFlat) then
   begin
    Inherited WndProc(Message);
    Case TAbPosition of
    tpTop : begin
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Left:=0;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Right:=ClientWidth;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Top:=PRect(Message.LParam)^.Top-4;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Bottom:=ClientHeight;
  end;
    tpLeft : begin
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Top:=0;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Right:=ClientWidth;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Left:=PRect(Message.LParam)^.Left-4;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Bottom:=ClientHeight;
  end;
    tpBottom : begin
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Left:=0;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Right:=ClientWidth;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Bottom:=PRect(Message.LParam)^.Bottom-4;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Top:=0;
  end;
    tpRight : begin
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Top:=0;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Left:=0;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Right:=PRect(Message.LParam)^.Right-4;
    PRect(Message.LParam)^.Bottom:=ClientHeight;
    end;
  end;
 end else Inherited WndProc(Message);

end;
```

The thing is when I tried something similar on the main application it won't work. It won't even compile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the tabs are drawn as buttons, no border is drawn around the display area, so set the `Style` property to `tsButtons` or `tsFlatButtons`. (For non-VCL programmers, this is equivalent to including the [`tcs_Buttons`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760549.aspx) window style on the tab control.)

An alternative is to use a `TNotebook`. It holds pages, but it doesn't do any painting at all. You'd have to provide the tabs yourself, such as by setting the tab control's height equal to the height of the tabs, or by using a `TTabSet`. (`TTabSet` is available in Delphi 2005; I'm not sure about Delphi 7.)

Regarding the code you found, it would be helpful if you indicated why it doesn't compile, or if you gave a link to where you found it, since I suppose the compilation error was because it refers to fields or properties of the custom class rather than the stock one. Here's what you can try to put it in your own code, without having to write a custom control.

Make two new declarations in your *form* like this:

```
FOldTabProc: TWndMethod;
procedure TabWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
```

In the form's `OnCreate` event handler, assign that method to the page control's `WindowProc` property:

```
FOldTabProc := PageControl1.WindowProc;
PageControl1.WindowProc := TabWndProc;
```

Now implement that method and handle the `tcm_AdjustRect` messsage:

```
procedure TForm1.TabWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  FOldTabProc(Msg);
  if Msg.Msg = tcm_AdjustRect then begin
    case PageControl1.TabPosition of
      tpTop: begin
        PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Left := 0;
        PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Right := PageControl1.ClientWidth;
        Dec(PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Top, 4);
        PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Bottom := PageControl1.ClientHeight;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You can fill in the other three cases if you need them. `Tcm_AdjustRect` is a message identifier declared in the *CommCtrl* unit. If you don't have that message in that unit, declare it yourself; its value is 4904.

I suspect this doesn't stop the control from drawing its borders. Rather, it causes the contained `TTabSheet` to grow a little bigger and cover up the borders.

Comment: Thanks, but as i mentioned on my question I don't want tsFlatButtons.

Comment: Then use non-flat buttons. The point is that the page control goes flat when the tabs are buttons, whatever kind of buttons they are.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. But NO. I need to use tabs  and no buttons.
I was very specific in my question. I even wrote a snippet detailing how someone did it.

Comment: and no, this is not a possible solution and i'd like to get the count back to zero on this comment but I can't.

Comment: Well, no, you weren't specific in your question. You said that you weren't asking how to make the tabs flat. You were asking how to make the rest of the control flat. And the way you do that is by making the tabs be buttons. You didn't say that the tabs must remain looking like tabs.

Comment: This is what I wrote:
"Now, the TPageControl under Delphi has no flat property (no I don't mean setting the tabstyle to flat buttons) or the borders cannot be set to "none" and it looks pretty bad when you add a text editor into the tab control."

No buttons, unless my english is not good, in which case i apologize

Comment: Apology accepted. Set the style to tsButtons if you want. They're not flat, but they do make the rest of the control flat, and that's what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks

the code fails in tcm_AdjustRect what is that? and FOldTabProc: TWndMethod; should be FOldWndMethod: TWndMethod;

Comment: ok, add CommCtrl to the units and that's it. this one works. thanks

Comment: @RobKennedy Hi. Your solution with TCM_ADJUSTRECT works, the only problem I have is that the borders are still visible immediately after the form is created, though they disappear after I resize the form. How to make them invisible immediately? Thank you

Comment: Please ask in a new question, @Smsrecv.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a commercial solution.  I would strongly recommend [Raize components](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/Default.asp), which support flat TPageControls with tabs.  The component set is very easy to work with, and supports numerous visual enhancements which in my opinion give a better feel to any application.

[image: screen shot of tTPageControl with flat borders]
<sub>(source: [raize.com](https://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/images/ContextMenu.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks. But 1) I already found a solution and 2) since this is a personal program I don't see the need to pay for a compoment

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Delphi XE8 and the following seems to do the trick:

```
ATabControl.Tabs.Clear;
ATabControl.Style := TTabStyle.tsFlatButtons;
ATabControl.Brush.Color := clWhite;
```

Comment: I clicked downvote during review, because question is about `Delphi 7` not `Delphi XE8`. I didn't know, that votes added during review, are not removed after finish review process (answer published or removed). Unfortunately I cannot unvote now.

Comment: No problem. I was just curious and I'd say if it possibly helps someone who stumbles upon this, as along as it is clearly marked as which version this concerns, I'd personally prefer such related answers to be encouraged. But I'm new here and am not yet perfectly familiar with the whole structure of the site and the conventions as to how to deal with it. Thanks for the feedback anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Drop two `TPageControl`s, one with tabs as `Tab`s, with a global height equal to the tabs, and one with flatbuttons and `Tabvisible` properties set to false, which would be aligned under the first one. Then make sure the tab change on the first `TPagecontrol` makes the tabs also change in the second one.