# Delphi. Remove a border of TabSheet of PageControl

Tags: delphi, tabs, border

Is it possible to remove a border of TabSheet (~4px)? I am using PageControl as a switch-panel instead of frames, windows etc. I want everything will be straight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a TPageControl flat in Delphi 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049033/making-a-tpagecontrol-flat-in-delphi-7)

Answer (score 23):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  ...,
  CommCtrl;

type
  TPageControl = class(ComCtrls.TPageControl)
  private
    procedure TCMAdjustRect(var Msg: TMessage); message TCM_ADJUSTRECT;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  end;

...

procedure TPageControl.TCMAdjustRect(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if Msg.WParam = 0 then
    InflateRect(PRect(Msg.LParam)^, 4, 4)
  else
    InflateRect(PRect(Msg.LParam)^, -4, -4);
end;

...

end.
```

Comment: @Michael: I don't know, no space here. Maybe it has something to do with the contents of a sheet?

Comment: @Michael About the extra space on top: See `TCustomTabControl.GetDisplayRect`. So if `TabPosition = tpTop`, you want to decrease the top by 2 pixels.

Comment: with this solution there are still several pixels of blank spaces on the top, to completely remove those blanks:
  if self.TabPosition = tpTop then
  begin
    PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Left := 0;
    PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Right := self.ClientWidth;
    Dec(PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Top, 4);
    PRect(Msg.LParam)^.Bottom := self.ClientHeight;
  end
  else
    inherited;

Comment: Strange, this solution works for some tab sheets, but not others. It only applies to the first tab sheet in the page control, but not the others. Very strange. I don't care about blank space. I only care about removing the border line. PS - I'm using VCL Styles in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but I have the same issue without styles. Doesn't appear to have anything to do with the tab contents.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind using third-party tools then the easiest solution would probably be to use TjvPageControl from [JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/). It has ClientBorderWidth property which you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a TTabSet with a TPageControl: In the onCreate event of the form, place this code to hide the tab.

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    I : Integer;
begin
   for I := 0 to Pred(PageControl1.PageCount) do
       PageControl1.Pages[I].TabVisible := False;
   PageControl1.Style := tsFlatButtons;
   PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := 0;

   TabSet1.Style := tsModernPopout;
   TabSet1.SelectedColor := clMoneyGreen;
   TabSet1.UnselectedColor := clGradientActiveCaption;
   TabSet1.SelectedColor := clGradientActiveCaption;
end;


procedure TMainForm.TabSet1Change(Sender: TObject; NewTab: Integer;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
   PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := NewTab;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

nowadays, that is the answer. No need any code hacks
 Probably you use themes, if not, you should use that technology:

- Project Options > Application> Appearance
- Check on one of them as Default Style) 
    
   than :
- Tools > Bitmap Style Designer > Open Style
- Navigate your vsf style file
   
  (probably right here
  "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio[VERSION]\Styles
- Now In Bitmap Style Designer.. navigate to:
  Objects > Tabs > Frame > Bitmap
- Click [...] three dot button of Bitmap In Inspector
- Zoom to 800%
- Pan/Scroll and Focus on to bitmap rectangle range.
- Right Mouse Click to change Upper-Left, Left Mouse Click to change Lower-Right
  region.
  (so select inner rectangle to eliminate border bitmap
  now you have borderless page controls)