# How can I remove the margin between a page control and its tab sheets?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

I noticed that the Left property for TTabSheet in the TPageControl is always 4. Because of this there is always at least a 4-pixel margin between the TPageControl border and controls within the TTabSheet. I want to set this margin to 0 (at least for the left border), but I can't set TTabSheet.Left to 0; it always automatically reverts to 4 pixels.

I tried to set the Left property in the OnResize for TTabSheet and for TTabControl, but it doesnt't help.

How can I reduce this margin to 0 (at least for the left border)? I'm using C++ Builder 6.

Comment: I don't think 0 is going to be viable because that would impinge on the border of the page control

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049033/making-a-tpagecontrol-flat-in-delphi-7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi. Remove a border of TabSheet of PageControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274626/delphi-remove-a-border-of-tabsheet-of-pagecontrol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As origional poster noted in comments.

Solution was

[Making a TPageControl flat in Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049033/making-a-tpagecontrol-flat-in-delphi-7)